# Python HTML displaying web link

Tags: python, html, tags

For some reason this code isn't displaying the link. I get an error message instead. Is there something I'm missing here?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

print("Content-type: text/html\n")

print("<a href='http://arctic-sign-658.appspot.com'>arctic-sign-658.appspot.com</a>")
```

I get this error when I type the URL:

> CGIWrap Error: Script Execution Failed
>
> CGIWrap encountered an error while attempting to execute this script:
>
> Error Message: No such file or directory Error Number: 2

This message usually indicates there is a problem with the script itself. Often this indicates either that the `#!` line of the script is incorrect, or the script was uploaded in binary mode instead of ascii mode. Check to make sure that the script does not have control-M's at the end of every line. That will prevent it from executing. An easy fix that takes care of this most of the time is to put `#!/.../perl --` instead of `#!/.../perl` on the first line of the script. This is typically a problem if the script was edited or uploaded from a DOS/Windows/Macintosh station to a unix based server.

If you are not the owner of this script, please forward this error and the URL that caused it to the script owner. That is often the component in the URL right after /cgiwrap/.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting this script to do?

Comment: i just want to create a link that is displayed on a website: arctic-sign-658.appspot.com

Comment: This is completely wrong. I'm sorry, but that's not how Python works. That's not how any of this works. I'm really not sure how to explain this in a way you'll understand, but this is just, I mean, it's wrong.

Comment: really but this code was provided by my professor so i was guessing i just need to tweek it a bit to make it work or he screwed up somewhere

Comment: Nevermind, this is a CGI script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your shebang line:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Doesn't point to an actual Python executable. Make sure you have Python installed on your web server, and that this is the path to the Python executable.

Comment: i currently have python 3 installed and everything should work fine since my previous work all work and they all used the same shebang